# SwiftUI: Cannot find model in scope?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
@Observable class Car {
    var year:Int
    init(year:Int) {
        self.year = year
    }
}


struct CarView: View {
//    @State var model = Car(year: 1) // <-- works
    @Environment(Car.self) var model:Car // <-- Error: Cannot find '$model' in scope
    var body: some View {
        CarSubView(year: $model.year)
    }
}


struct CarSubView: View {
    @Binding var year:Int
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            year += year
        } label: {
            Text("TEST")
        }
    }
}
```

So I don't understand why I get the error `Cannot find '$model' in scope` when I use the `@Environment(Car.self) var model:Car` instead of `@State var model = Car(year: 1)`.

I am passing the Car model via the environment and I was thinking I could then pass the year binding to the `CarSubView`.

How can I pass the year as binding to `CarSubView` when model comes to the view via environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CarView as follows:

```
struct CarView: View {
    @Environment(Car.self) var model: Car

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model // <-- this is the key part
        CarSubView(year: $model.year)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works. Is this how we're supposed to do this? I just don't see it here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

Comment: Check this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bindable

Comment: bingo. I missed that in the docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> this should do the trick

```
    class Car: ObservableObject {
    var year: Int
    init(year:Int) {
        self.year = year
    }
}


struct CarView: View {
//    @ObservedObject var model: Car
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Car // if you want to inject into the environment
    
    var body: some View {
        CarSubView(year: $model.year)
            .environmentObject(model)
    }
}


struct CarSubView: View {
    @Binding var year: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            year += year
        } label: {
            Text("TEST")
        }
    }
}
```